# HSV value for black

Tags: opencv, hsv

I'm writing a C++ code which can identify color black.  I want to use HSV color space, but I cannot find the value range for black.  Can anybody provide me the value range for color black in HSV color space?

Comment: think of it, black, white or any shade of grey are not a color

Comment: use HSL color space and the lightness channel. http://colorizer.org/

Answer (score 9):

In the HSV color space black color is represented by any point (H,S,V) having V = 0. To visualise this see the cylindrical 3D models in the [HSV wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) which make it very easy to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Black hairs filter

```
hair_color_low=[0,0,0]
hair_color_high=[360,255,50]
```

[image: BLACK HAIRS2]
[image: BLACK HAIRS]